# VB.NET How to Update DataSource from DataGridView (Binding to Dataset.DataTable)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable, visual-studio-2019

Halo All..

I'm working with Visual Studio 2019 to create WinFormApp

What i'm working with as follow:

1. Adding New `DataSource` from wizard which connect to Acces Database (store locally within app), Acces Database name is Supplier with only Headers (9 Headers) and no data.
2. Adding `DataGridView` to `Form` and bind it to `SupplierDataSet.SupplierDataTable`
3. Adding OpenFileDialog where users can browse Excel File then select Sheet Name and view the data in `DataGridView`.
4. Adding Import Button to save/update `SupplierDataSet.SupplierDataTable`

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports ExcelDataReader

Public Class Form2

    Dim tables As DataTableCollection

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBrowse.Click

       'read excel file
        Using ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog() With
                            {.Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx"}

            If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                TxtFileName.Text = ofd.FileName
                Using stream = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                    Using reader As IExcelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)
                        Dim result As DataSet = reader.AsDataSet(New ExcelDataSetConfiguration() With {
                                 .ConfigureDataTable = Function(__) New ExcelDataTableConfiguration() With {
                                 .UseHeaderRow = True}})
                        tables = result.Tables
                        CboSheet.Items.Clear()
                        For Each table As DataTable In tables
                            CboSheet.Items.Add(table.TableName)
                        Next
                    End Using
                End Using
            End If
        End Using

    End Sub

    Private Sub CboSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CboSheet.SelectedIndexChanged

       'Pupulate excel file data to DataGridView
        Dim dt As DataTable = tables(CboSheet.SelectedItem.ToString())
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnImport.Click

       'Here the code which I want to save/update SupplierDataSet.SupplierDataTable.

    End Sub
End Class
```

Since i'm new for this (approx 2 weeks). I've no clue to how to update the `DataTable`

Please Help Me. Any help will be appreciated.
And So Many Thanks Before.

Comment: It seems I must add a reference or get a Nuget to use ExcelDataReader. Can your give me a clue?

Comment: You're using a package called ExcelData**Reader** and it is described thusly: *"Lightweight and fast library written in C# for reading Microsoft Excel files (2.0-2007)"*. Clearly you don't use that to write changes to the file. That means that you need to use some other means, and you can find those other means using a search engine. If you want to SAVE a DATATABLE to EXCEL in VB.NET, the appropriate search keywords are not exactly hard to determine.

Comment: @Mary - ExcelDataReader can be installed directly to project via Manage Nuget Package in Project Menu.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I'm not going to change the Excel File. The project is read Excel File, display to `DataGridView`, then store in `SupplierDataSet.SupplierDataTable`. Therefor i can reuse the data that has stored to next code in other Form. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you have created a typed DataSet from an Access database and that you want to read data from an Excel file into an instance of that and then save to Access?

Comment: @jmcilhinney - That's correct. I've created Blank Access Database (Only Header) and created DataSet from that. Next i've imported Excel File then display the data in `DataGridView`, but I cannot store it to DataSet.DataTable i've created earlier.

Comment: Your `DataTable` has a `Load` method, to which you can pass any data reader, including an `ExcelDataReader` to populate it with the data you read. I'm not 100% sure what happens regarding mapping columns with names that don't match but you can look into that.

Comment: If worse comes to worst, you can create a standard `DataTable` and call `Load` on that, then rename columns as required, then create a `DataTableReader` on that and pass it to the `Load` method of the final `DataTable`. If the `RowState` of each row is `Unchanged` by default, you can call `SetAdded` on each one. You can then use the appropriate table adapter to save the changes.